# Find, highlight and list count of instances of words found in document using VBA

Tags: vba, count, ms-word, match, highlight

I have a list of keywords that I need to search for in Word documents.

I made a script that searches the document and highlights all instances found, including matching all word forms (i.e. fix, fixed, fixing).  After processing, a message box appears that is supposed to summarize the count of instances found for each word.

The problem is that although the highlighting routine allows for all word forms (.MatchAllWordForms = True), I'm missing something for the count, such that only exact matches are tallied.

Can you help me update this so that all words and word forms are both highlighted and summarized in the message box?

```
'
    ' Highlight Macro

    Sub HighlightKeywords()


    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Keywords

    ' put list of terms to find here

    Keywords = Array("wrong", "broke", "fix", "swap", "missing", "mistake", "revert", "oops", "backwards", "shatter", "drop")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Keywords)

    Set range = ActiveDocument.range

    With range.Find
    .Text = Keywords(i)
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True

    Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
    range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    Loop

    End With

    Next

    ReDim numfound(0 To UBound(Keywords))

        For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
            idx = 0
            For Each var In Keywords
                If Trim(wrd.Text) = Keywords(idx) Then
                    numfound(idx) = numfound(idx) + 1
                End If
                idx = idx + 1
            Next var
        Next wrd

        idx = 0
        For Each var In Keywords
            strResults = strResults & Keywords(idx) & " : " & _
                         numfound(idx) & vbCr
            idx = idx + 1
        Next var

        MsgBox strResults


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A message box has very limited output capacity. If you really want to go down that path, try:

```
Sub HighlightKeywords()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Keywords, StrOut As String
' put list of terms to find here
Keywords = Array("wrong", "broke", "fix", "swap", "missing", "mistake", "revert", "oops", "backwards", "shatter", "drop")
For i = 0 To UBound(Keywords)
  j = 0
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .Text = Keywords(i)
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchAllWordForms = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found = True
      j = j + 1
      .Duplicate.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
  StrOut = StrOut & vbCr & Keywords(i) & ": " & j
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Found the following:" & StrOut
End Sub
```