# Microsoft Word macro to highlight complete words ending in a set of terms

Tags: ms-word, highlight, search-multiple-words

(This question builds on an already existing and resolved question, to be found here: [Microsoft Word Macro for highlighting multiple words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399655/microsoft-word-macro-for-highlighting-multiple-words))

1.The goal is to highlight in a full-text Word document only those words **ending** on a word in a string, and mark those **entire** words (not just the corresponding part). The idea is to simplify grammar correction by highlighting words that are frequently used in an erroneous way.

For example, the string ("more”, “ever”) applied on the following text:

*Evermore, moreover. Everyday, forever.*

Should mark the (entire) first and last word but not the words in between.

2. The list of terms I have made counts up to 800 words. Inserting this in the below code gives the error “the string is too long”. Likely, the only solution is to work with a separate document and to refer the code to that document. Any ideas on how this should be solved most elegantly? And if an in-code solution is not ideal, what format must the separate document have?

3. How to show a message box, once the macro is executed, informing you on how many words have been highlighted (or none)? In the above example: "two words were found".

Thanks a lot for your help.

Willem

This is the already provided code that might be a good start off:

```
Sub highlightWords()

Dim range As range
TargetList = Array("lastwordpart1", "lastwordpart2", "lastwordpart3") ' list of terms to find is too long for this string…

For Each Target In TargetList

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
  .Text = Target
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False

  Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
    range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray25
  Loop

End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by other questions and answers, I managed to create a macro that did most of the actions I wanted. Finally, I saved the word list in a macro template (.dotm) in the Word STARTUP folder. The macro refers to this file as the target list.

Essentially, the macro uses the find and replace function with wildcards. The words in the target list are changed to make this work. Here is an example: To find the word "never", the term is modified to [N,n]ever>. The > indicates that the word ends after the search term. For example, "Nevermore" is not marked. This is intentional.

There are still three problems with this:

1.
Wildcards are case sensitive. This makes it difficult to find the word with and without upper case letters. My workaround is to only find words with and without the first letter in upper case. Words written entirely in upper case will not be found. This is a flaw, but I thought that words written entirely in capitals are mostly rare in full texts. This explains the [N,n] in the search term [N,n]ever. For your interest, putting every letter in brackets is too difficult for the search engine, it gave an error when trying.

Ideas on how to achieve this regardless of case are welcome.

2.
I did not manage to highlight the whole word. There was a method, but it required me to replace the first letter of the word with <[!^09-^13 ]@. In the example above, this would be <[!^09-^13 ]@ever>. It will mark the whole words that contain "never", such as "whenever", but it will also mark words like "bever", "clever", etc., which is unwanted. I decided not to use this solution as it resulted in too many unwanted hits.

Ideas are welcome on how to mark the whole word without having to remove letters from the initial search term.

3.
I found other sources on this platform on how to give a message box that counts the highlighted words (such as: [Find, highlight and list count of instances of words found in document using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332126/find-highlight-and-list-count-of-instances-of-words-found-in-document-using-vba)), but I did not understand it well enough to implement it. So I ended up with a simple message box that tells you when the macro is finished.

I can live without it, but if it's not too much trouble, suggestions are welcome.

Here is the final code.

```
Sub Highlighter()
 Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
  Dim FRDoc As Document, FRList() As String, i As Long, aRng As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
  Set FRDoc = Documents.Open(Application.StartupPath & "\Highlighter.dotm", 
  ReadOnly:=True, Addtorecentfiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  FRList = Split(FRDoc.Range.Text, vbCr)
  FRDoc.Close False
  Set FRDoc = Nothing
  Set aRng = Selection.Range
  With aRng.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Replacement.ClearFormatting
   .MatchWholeWord = True
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWildcards = True
   .Wrap = wdFindStop
   .Replacement.Text = "^&"
   .Replacement.Highlight = True
   For i = 0 To UBound(FRList)
     If Trim(FRList(i)) <> "" Then
       .Text = Trim(FRList(i))
       .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     End If
  Next
  End With
MsgBox "Job done."
End Sub
```